# destroy cookies when closing the tab

Tags: jquery, cookies, colorbox

I am building a website in wp and in the homepage I have a colorbox which loads on page load. I wanted to show that colorbox just once . In order to do that I used the following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        jQuery.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
    }
});
```

This solved my problem. But after this came another requirement that the colorbox should load after closing and reopening the tab. I dont know what changes I have to make inorder to achieve my goal. Can anyone help me here?

**UPDATE:**

Following is the purpose of using the colorbox

This colorbox is just like a facebook like box popup. I need to show only once when the user visits the site on the homepage. When the user click on the homepage it should not come again.. and if the user closes the tab or browser and go to that link again the colorbox should appear

Hope this will help you to understand more about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement seems to defeat the purpose : it looks like the colorwheel should be opened once each time the user opens a new page.

Once the colorwheel is closed, is there no way for the user to open it again ? I would suggest adding a button "Show/hide colorwheel".

On page load : open it if cookie is not present, or leave it hidden otherwise.

Comment: This colorbox is just like a facebook like box popup. I need to show only once when the user visits the site on the homepage. When the user click on the homepage it should not come again.. and if the user closes the tab or browser and go to that link again the colorbox should appear